# How to fetch two tables and sort the data by date?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need a query that fetches data fron two tables and sort them by date.

**Table 1: Invoice**

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("select * from invoice where customer = 95");
?>
ID     Customer     Amount     Date
1      95           1500       01-Apr-2017
2      95           5500       09-Apr-2017
3      95           22000      10-Apr-2017
4      95           35000      11-Apr-2017
```

**Table 2: Payments**

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("select * from Payments where customer = 95");
?>
ID     Customer     Amount     Date
1      95           10000      02-Apr-2017
2      95           11000      09-Apr-2017
3      95           22000      11-Apr-2017
4      95           1200       15-Apr-2017
```

I need output as below:

```
ID     Date           InvoiceDR     InvoiceCR
1      01-Apr-2017    1500          -
2      02-Apr-2017     -            10000
3      09-Apr-2017    5500          -
4      09-Apr-2017     -            11000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT invoice.id, NULL AS invoiceDR, invoice.InvoiceCR, invoice.Date FROM invoice)
UNION ALL
(SELECT NULL AS id, paymentd.InvoiceCR, NULL AS InvoiceDR, payments.Date FROM Payments)
) results ORDER BY Date ASC");
```

put order by date in end of the query
and change order of date as per your need

Comment: i need to fetch data between two tables invoice and payment order by date

Comment: in which table date field is available ?

Comment: And can you please explain me InvoiceDR     and InvoiceCR in table tame

Comment: date fields are available in both tables i need to fetch data where customer = 96 order by date (i need date sequence asc combine both tables) i think join or goup should be use here but i dont know how to use it

Comment: actually i want to create statement (general-ledger)... <br/> sno -- date -- credit -- debit

Comment: Please can you send me screenshot of what you get with my current query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141694/discussion-between-suresh-suthar-and-hani-mehdi).

Answer (score 0):

You can use "order by" for this purpose. You can set order by ascending and descending (ASC or DESC). Use this query.

```
select * from Invoice,Payments where '{condition}' order by Invoice.Date ASC , Payemnts.Date ASC
```

This query will firstly sort the data according to first table(Invoice) and then sorted data will sorted with second table(Payemnts)